# Does the repos in maven not have jar files?

Tags: maven

I have tried looking through various repos around, however i could not find one that contains the jar file for this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>jre</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0_131</version>
</dependency>
```

Error i got: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.blackducksoftware.test:example-maven-travis:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.oracle.java:jre:jar:1.8.0_131 in jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss)

Is there a reason why only pom files are in the repo and not the jar file?
How do I get the jar file?

Answer (score 1):

[From mvnrepository.com:](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.java/jre/1.8.0_131)

> Note: this artifact it located at Alfresco repository (https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/)

So you need to add a profile entry to your settings.xml file.

**Example:**

```xml
 <profile>
            <id>alfresco-repo</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>alfresco-repo</id>
                    <name>Alfresco Repository</name>
                    <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this repository. However what i meant was that there is no .jar file. Hence the error message.

Comment: I see that it contains tar archives and not jar. I'm wondering why would you need to include this as a dependency? Shouldn't this be installed on the system level instead?

Comment: I am trying to use the owasp plugin to find cves. So I am trying to add the jre into the dependencies.